# How to return success message after the process is done in PHP OOP

Tags: php

I have a Class named `Register.class.php` which goes like this:

```
    <?php 
class Register
{   
    private $db;
    public function __construct()
    {
       $this->db = new Connection();
       $this->db = $this->db->dbConnect();
    }
    public function NewAdmin($username,$email,$password,$groups,$level)
    {
        if(!empty($username)&&!empty($email)&&!empty($password)&&!empty($groups)&&!empty($level))
        {
            $reg = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO admins (user_name, email_address, password_hash, group_admin, date_joined, admin_level) VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ?, NOW(), ?)");
            $reg->bindParam(1,$username);
            $reg->bindParam(2,$email);
            $reg->bindParam(3,$password);
            $reg->bindParam(4,$groups);
            $reg->bindParam(5,$level);
            $reg->execute();
        }
    }
}
?>
```

And I call this method like this:

```
$registration = new Register();
$registration->NewAdmin($username,$email,$password,$groups,$level);
```

But now I want to show a success message like *New Admin Has Been Added* inside the `NewAdmin` method...

So please can you tell me how can I do that?

Comment: I would recommend that `NewAdmin()` returns true if added and then output the message in your calling code.  This allows you to use it anywhere without output side effects.

Comment: Can you show me what you mean

Answer (score 1):

It depends if you are using PHP 7.2

```
 public function NewAdmin($username,$email,$password,$groups,$level):bool
{
    if(!empty($username)&&!empty($email)&&!empty($password)&&!empty($groups)&&!empty($level))
    {
        $reg = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO admins (user_name, email_address, password_hash, group_admin, date_joined, admin_level) VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ?, NOW(), ?)");
        $reg->bindParam(1,$username);
        $reg->bindParam(2,$email);
        $reg->bindParam(3,$password);
        $reg->bindParam(4,$groups);
        $reg->bindParam(5,$level);
        return $reg->execute();
   }
   return false;
}


$registration = new Register();
$test = $registration->NewAdmin($username,$email,$password,$groups,$level);
echo ($test ? "TRUE ADMIN ADDED" : "FALSE ADMIN NOT CREATED");
```

Also check the manual at http://php.net/manual/en/functions.returning-values.php for more documentation.

Do note if you are using PHP7.1 < the ':bool' return type can not be used on the function.

Comment: Just to be a pain; I'd return `$reg->execute()` as your code will actually return true even if the `->execute()` call failed. I'd throw a final `return false;` at the end of the method  to capture any other issues that make the `if()` fail

Answer (score 0):

Could you not do a simple

`return "New Admin created";`

inside the function, upon checking the action was successful?

Please bear in mind that at the moment your code relies on everything working, you are not checking if anything actually succeeded, you are not catching any exceptions and you are most definitely not dealing with any errors.

Moreover, you could then extend this and return different messages depending on errors, exceptions or missing values.

I would not rely on !empty as the only way of verifying my variables either, unless they are known to be correct by some other algorithm or part of the website (if you do not verify them, I would suggest using some sort of library or php built in functions as a minimum).